# Installing Apache Lucene for LAMP server

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, search-engine, lucene

I have Ubuntu running for LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP) server. To provide better search  capability one of my friend recommended to install "Apache Lucene".

While reading about it I came to know that "Apache Lucene" required tomcat and java to run. Please let me know if it be feasible to have it or there are other better alternates for LAMP stack.

I am looking for some proven solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). Lucene is a library, while Solr is a Tomcat application, much more likely what your friend was thinking of.